# How to pass object from android mobile to android wear?

Tags: android, wear-os

I tried different ways to pass class object using DataMap but its not correct way. Please suggest any way to pass class object from phone to wear.

Comment: whathave you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check these SO threads [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028423/share-objects-from-phone-to-android-wear) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24595679/how-to-use-dataitem-of-android-wear) on how to use `DataMap` to pass and retrieve the object. The way to access previously stored data is with the [`DataApi`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataApi.html) methods. For example, you can get all stored data with `Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can pass String you can pass serialized object of your class.

So you can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library for object serialization and deserialization.